# Passing arguments to functions from a dll loaded with ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call from my Python code a simple function from a dll, build with QtCreator, and the problem is that argument size is always invalid.

Here's my **test.h** (***test.cpp*** is empty):

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include "test_global.h"

extern "C"
{

   int TESTSHARED_EXPORT si () { return sizeof(int);}

   int TESTSHARED_EXPORT add4 ( int i) { return i + 4;}
}


#endif // TEST_H
```

It builds to test.dll, which I'm able to load with:

```
tdll = windll.LoadLibrary(r'X:\TMP\SRC\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\test.dll')
```

Calling `print tdll.si()` prints 4 as expected,
but all calls to `tdll.add4(1)` fail with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    print tdll.add4(2)
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)
```

Same thing happens if I wrap `add4` argument into `c_int, c_uint, c_int32` or any other `*int` type, provided by ctypes.

Please, help me fix this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the symptoms of a calling convention mismatch. Probably your exported functions are `__cdecl`, but your ctypes code uses `__stdcall`. Your question does not have enough information for me to be sure of that but it's very likely and does explain the reported behaviour.

Resolve the mismatch by using `cdll` instead of `windll`. Using `windll` results in `__stdcall` being used, using `cdll` results in `__cdecl` being used.